# Is it possible to draw a shape based on an onClick Event in React JS using react-konva?

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I am looking for a way to draw a shape based on a mouse event in react-konva, but have only been able to find methods to draw shapes on the screen statically

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add onClick event to your Stage like  `<Stage width={yourWidth} height={yourHeight} ref={stageRef} onClick={handleClick}>` and then

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    setCircles((prevCircles) => [
      ...prevCircles,
      {
        x: e.currentTarget.pointerPos.x,
        y: e.currentTarget.pointerPos.y,
        fill: "blue"
      }
    ]);
  }
```

and don't forget to .map your circles state inside of Stage ;)

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to use your methode to create a <Shape/> could you maybe help me?